# copy values from enums in different namespaces

Tags: c#, .net

I have two classes `MyObj` and `MyObjDTO` both have a matchin enum property `StarRating`.

```
public class MyObj
{
    public enum StarRating {
         One = 1,
         Two = 2
    }
}

public class MyObjDTO
{
    public enum StarRating {
         One = 1,
         Two = 2
    }
}
```

I want to assign value from `MyObjDTO` to `MyObj`. I tried

```
var dto = ... loaded dto object

var data = new MyObj
            {
                ...
                RatingStatus = (int)dto.RatingStatus
            };
```

But It doesn't work, I'm getting underlined error under int and simple

```
 RatingStatus = dto.RatingStatus
```

doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4):

You're gonna be casting like hell in order to do this perversion:

```
var data = new MyObj
{
    RatingStatus = (MyObj.StarRating)(int)dto.RatingStatus,
};
```

So you should really refactor your code and reuse this `StarRating` enumeration instead of duplicating it in both classes as you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Your `StarRating` type is not a property - it is type more accurate a enumeration.

I think the simpliest way is to convert the value to an `int` and then to the expected type:

```
RatingStatus = (MyObj.StarRating)(int)dto.RatingStatus
```

But I recommend to use only one `StarRating` enum at both places.

Answer (score 0):

You can direct cast because the underlying type is int. However, you should ensure that the values are identical in both enums or refactor as Darin suggests.

```
public enum StarRating1
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}

public enum StarRating2
{
    One = StarRating1.One,
    Two = StarRating1.Two
}

var sr1 = StarRating1.One;
var sr2 = (StarRating2) sr1;
```